# "shell request failed on channel 0", "Permission denied (publickey)" but "Authentication succeeded" on Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to use SSH to clone a repository, instead of HTTPS, to see if the speed is faster (it's a large repository). One member of my organization at work has successfully authenticated and cloned the repository (same I am trying to clone), but mine  keeps failing.

```
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.website.com/repo/repo.git
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

When I try to SSH into the server with `-Tv` flags, I get this output:

```
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.website.com ([123.123.123]:7999).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
shell request failed on channel 0
```

As you can see, it authenticates me properly but for some reason replies with `shell request failed on channel 0`

I have entered my SSH public key into https://bitbucket.website.com/plugins/servlet/ssh/account/keys/add (which starts with `ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXX`)

I have verified with `ssh-keygen` that the private key `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` does have the public key I attached in Bitbucket.

My private key **IS** password protected. Something I know for a fact that nobody else has.

The other guy's private key is **not** password protected.

The other guy's SSH URL is `initials@bitbucket.website.com` wheras Bitbucket automatically shows `git@bitbucket.website.com` for me. I did try to use my initials instead, but that yields the exact same response.

Many people have had this issue on StackOverflow as well, but I see them marking an answer as the correct, but those did not work for me. I'm pretty lost here.

Comment: Try and enable some debug at the terminal: `export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 export GIT_TRACE=1 export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` - then retry the clone. It might give some useful info.

Comment: @eeijlar Didn't change the output at all, unfortunately. Still the same "Permission denied (publickey)"

Comment: Run each export as a separate command,  or if running as one command then delimit each command with a semi-colon

Comment: `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE` is only relevant to HTTP-based connections. `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"` is for SSH. You can add more `v` to get more verbose output.

Comment: It doesn't matter that your key is password-protected, or that your co-worker is using their initials (which are probably their Bitbucket username) rather than "git". Bitbucket's SSH system is also meant to handle Git traffic only, and not give you a full shell. With that said, though, the verbose output from `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.website.com/repo/repo.git` could help here.

Comment: @eeijlar I did do the semicolon between each command

Comment: @JimRedmond Unfortunately it gave me no extra verbose output. Still the same `Permission denied (publickey)` error

Comment: That's strange, are you sure it's a bash terminal?

Comment: @eeijlar Yep. I'm using WSL on Windows. Ubuntu version :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into what seems like the same issue. Once I changed my `git clone` command to include the port (in my case the default 7999), it worked. I included the port when I tried using `ssh -T`, but forgot when attempting the actual `git clone` command.

```
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.website.com:7999/repo/repo.git
```

From Atlassian Documentation at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/enabling-ssh-access-to-git-repositories-in-bitbucket-server-776640358.html

"For example, if the SSH base URL is not set and the Bitbucket Server base URL is https://bitbucket.atlassian.com and the SSH port is 7999, the SSH URL for the repository Jira in the project Atlassian will be ssh://git@bitbucket.atlassian.com:7999/ATLASSIAN/jira.git"